# Does heavy theme and plugins affect server's response time?

Tags: plugins, themes, performance, google-chrome

I am building my website using TheSeven theme, with Visual Composer and Ultimate Addons For VC plugins. But my website run very very slow. It takes 6-7 seconds or sometimes higher to load my homepage: [here is my homepage](http://caosukythuatvietnam.vn)

I use google Pagespeed to test the website and optimized according to suggestions. But I cannot solve the "response time" problem. I use the same host service for another website and it run very fast. They said that my website consume a lot of resource, so the server cannot response as fast as normal. I am also suggested to change theme because my theme is heavy.

When I used Chrome Tool TimeLine to test my website, it shows a lot of "Recalculate Style" parts, with a warning "forced re-flow is likely a performance bottleneck". But I don't really understand.

What could be my main problem? Could it be caused by hosting, or it's because my theme is too heavy?

Comment: It is impossible to give an exact answer. Anything anywhere can cause slow loading times. Download and install Query Monitor, then examine the results to see which queries are hanging (*if this is query related*). Apart from that, you are better of hiring a developer to look into your site and optimizing it

Comment: not sure what is exactly the answer you expect to get here. you main problem is obvious - bad coding, but I am sure saying that is not very helpful. Aside problem is that your images are too big, but this is really aside of other probably more important problems.

Comment: The server respone time is not bad, but you are loading 23 different Google Fonts styles as well as 20 CSS files and 35 javascript files from your own domain, totalling more than 4 MB just in those assets. I would suggest having a look at the theme's typography options to simplify them and to install a plugin that concatenates and minifies CSS and Javascript.

Comment: @LuisSanz, server response time should be less then a second.The initial html is the biggest bottleneck and has to be as fast as possible

Comment: @MarkKaplun, I get an average response time of 0.7 in Spain and 0.54 in PageSpeed Insights which, while not being optimal, I think it's ok.

Comment: I get 5+ seconds in israel, maybe geo location plays a part here

Comment: Did some say Visual Composer? http://i.imgur.com/PNYRZ.gif

Comment: Just a suggest going off what @LuisSanz said about minifying CSS and JavaScript - there is a very good Plugin out there called WP Fastest Cache, this basically gives you setting to combine some of your JavaScript Files aswell and Minify your HTML and also combine your CSS files - I use this on most of my sites and it increases the loading speed of the site.

Comment: Thank you guys for very useful ideas. I will minify CSS and JS, and use cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've touched on a few things here, and there's both the server and the frontend response time that you're battling with. You might have issues with both.

It's worth noting firstly that PageSpeed (and the style recalcuating alert in the Chrome timeline) both deal with front-end aspects only - in slightly different ways though (another good tool to check out is [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/)).

As far as the backend goes, you could try the [Plugin Profiler plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) to see which plugins are causing the most issues. Or alternatively - and probably a much better solution - disable every plugin, change your theme, then enable one by one to see where the bottleneck is.

If there's a lot of style recalculations, it might be some bad coding on the part of your theme. If you can prove that the delay is due to your theme (by changing it to another one to see if the delay goes away), it might be worth writing to the theme authors to see if there's anything they can do about it.

Another item worth checking is the media on the page. Have you got any super large images that you could optimise, that could be adding to the time the browser takes to download your page?

In the end, there are many, many things that could be causing delays both on the backend and the frontend. You've already confirmed you have a good enough host because your other site is working fine, so the problem is going to lie *somewhere* within what is unique to this site.

Good luck and feel free to post comments/add additional information to your post if there's any aspect of this you have questions about!

Comment: Thank you! Plugin Profiler shows that Visual Composer and Ultimate Addons consume most website's resource. I am thinking about using another page builder. My theme also request a lot of css & js files. I will minify them.

Comment: No problem. W3 Total Cache might be handy for you too (for caching and minifying); also try Site Origin Page Builder as an alternative to Visual Composer.